# Viewbag para todas as controllers Asp.Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um aplicação em ASP.Net MVC, depois que o usuário faz o login preciso mostrar seu nome no topo da pagina sempre, independente de qual pagina ele está.

Essa aplicação é um administrativo onde ficará o nome da empresa na parte de cima, eu vi algumas soluções para o meu problema mas não consigo decidir qual seria  melhor, por ter pouco conhecimento.

1. Construir um controller base com a pesquisa do nome da empresa e retornando ela para uma *viewbag*.
2. Não me lembro bem pois não encontrei a pergunta novamente, mas era para usar o padrão `[discriminação]` nos *controllers* (caso alguém consiga me explicar como se faz).

Agora uma dúvida que tenho sobre *viewbag*, caso eu use a primeira opção e crie um *controller* que retorna para essa *viewbag*, como vou usá-las nas páginas? No caso preciso apenas usar na `Shared\_Layout`, certo ? Alguém conseguiria me da um exemplo?

Eu tenho pouca noção sobre essa parte o que esta dificultando meu aprendizado, gostaria de uma resposta um pouco mais didática sobre o funcionamento até mesmo das *viewbag*, eu encontrei outras respostas sobre esse assunto mas não consegui compreendê-las por completo.

Comment: Está usando o que para autenticação, Identity?

Comment: Não fiz a parte do login, mas acabei de fazer um pergunta sobre o login e pelo que vi não e identity, porque ele usa um arquivo para redirecionamento chamado 'Starup.Auth.cs'  e não possui este arquivo no projeto, eu fiz o redirecionamento no 'web.config' usando o '<authentication mode="Forms">'  não sei se ajuda .

Comment: Você utilizará este valor para alguma operação ou apenas para mostrar na tela?

Comment: Apenos mostro ela na tela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma de solucionar o seu problema utilizando as viewbags seria usando `partial view`, então você poderia colocar uma controller customizada definindo a viewbag e apenas dar um `@Html.RenderAction` na página de layout compartilhada do seu sistema. Dessa forma teriamos:

**html**
No exemplo vamos utilizar como _Nome.cshtml ela pode estar na mesma pasta do _Layout.cshtml

```
<div>
    @Viewbag.nome
</div>
```

**controller**
No exemplo vamos colocar como ActionController.cs

```
public PartialViewResult Action(){
    Viewbag.nome = "nome";
    return PartialView("~/views/Shared/_Nome.cshtml");

}
```

**_layout**

```
@Html.RenderAction("Action", "Action");
```

Agora existem diversas outra soluções sem utilizar `viewbag`.

Comment: Então eu estava querendo saber qual seria a forma mais indicada para o meu caso, por exemplo, o meu menu já _Partial , mas eu chamo ele como layout , e é nesse pagina que ficaria a informação que preciso compartilhar. Pode ser com ou sem viewbag, se for com gostaria de saber um pouco mias sobre a forma de aplicar .  Se possivel e claro , mas muito obrigado por sua resposta, vou tentar aqui

Comment: Você poderia dar uma explicação um pouco mais detalhada dessa controller customizada? eu tenho que criar essa controler e so atribuir a viewbag com o valor que eu preciso ?

Comment: Eu vou criar uma controller e uma view para essa controller , irei atribuir o valor da viewbag na controller e adicionar na minha  _Layout, @Partial_Html(NovaView) certo ?  estou um pouco de dificuldades de entender essa logica, depois que ue usar essa partial na minha layout eu ja consigo usar a viewbag ?

Comment: Só um segundo, vou tentar melhorar minha explicação

Comment: Pronto, tentei esclarecer o código e como fazer. Mudei a função de render para ver se facilitava também, qualquer duvida Tamo aí

Comment: Não consegui impleta da forma que você me disse , eu creiei um controle apenas com a Consulta e atribui o valor que eu precisava a Viewbag.Nome  e retornei a view que eu criei , segui o exemplo e puz o nome e  na layout chame essa _nome ,com o @Html.Patial ( o renderAction não funcionou) , mas nada de funcionar